# Create icon (Not shortcut) for ubuntu

Tags: icons

Well I said (Not shortcut) but I accept that I might be wrong.

"How can I create a .png that works for .desktop files."

I can create or edit a .desktop file and point to a .png created by lutris, but .png files I create show a default icon.

Same for .png files I download.

And I have done my best for a few hours now, but trying to find information on creating .png icons is very frustrating because of the 12 billion results on how to create a shortcut.
LOL
Thanks,

P.s. since my question is not clear (Maybe this is why I'm having a hard time finding help) I want to know how to create the file itself. (.png file) I tried GIMP and I tried simply downloading existing png files, but Ubuntu does not seem to like them.

Perhaps a better way to explain my question is what are the specific formatting requirements (Indexed, RGB) and /or export requirements (save background color, save color values from transparent pixels, etc) that I should be using in GIMP.
Or should I be using a different application all together?

The .desktop file is:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Name=StarCraft II
    Icon=lutris_starcraft-ii.png
    Exec=lutris lutris:rungameid/1
    Categories=Game
```

With or without the '.png' at the end of the Icon= line works with the png created by Lutris, but does not work with any png file I create or download.

P.S.S I am placing these files in:

```
    ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps
```

which is where the original files are that seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to discern the problem you are having without seeing your .desktop file. So let's try https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html. It's not the icon spec, but it seems close enough.

Oh, here's something:

> Icons and themes are looked for in a set of directories. By default, apps should look in $HOME/.icons (for backwards compatibility), in $XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons and in /usr/share/pixmaps (in that order). Applications may further add their own icon directories to this list, and users may extend or change the list (in application/desktop specific ways).In each of these directories themes are stored as subdirectories.

Ah, and here's more:

> Installing Application Icons
>
> So, you're an application author, and want to install application icons so that they work in the KDE and Gnome menus. Minimally you should install a 48x48 icon in the hicolor theme. This means installing a PNG file in $prefix/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps. Optionally you can install icons in different sizes. For example, installing a svg icon in $prefix/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps means most desktops will have one icon that works for all sizes. You might even want to install icons with a look that matches other well known themes so your application will fit in with some specific desktop environment.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Perhaps I am just too impatient. for some reason now it just works. No idea what is different. I started happening when I created the 48x48 folder, but new icons don't have to be in there.  Weird bug or crazy coincidence???